# Prevent dxBarManager toolbar from floating

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have dropped a dxManager1 on a form and added a toolbar. How do I prevent this toolbar from being dragged around? I don't want it to detach from the top of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `TdxBarManager` component then select it at Design Time, and set the `NotDocking` options in the Object Inspector to `True`.

This will prevent the Toolbar from been moved or docked around.